# 'Missing Beta Entitlement' while building through Visual-Studio-Cordova

Tags: iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I Have Developed a Hybdrid App in iOS using the Visual Studio Cordova using Ionic Framework. App was ready to Production deployment. Here i am facing a problem and will explain in two cases.

**Case 1 :** When i set provision Profile to distribution in Xcode and try to build using the Remote agent got the ipa file in my bin and when i try to upload this ipa using Application Loader it was successfully uploaded to the itunes Connect but showing that

> 'Missing Beta Entitlement'

**Case 2** : Instead of building through remote agent i went to platforms and copied the iOS folder and try to run in Mac using the Xcode and i am able to get the ipa file and got successfully uploaded to the itunes connect but it didn't show that warning Message (i.e.Missing Beta Entitlement') .

I am aware of that **Missing Beta Entitlement** is because i need to keep

```
 <key>beta-reports-active</key><true/>
```

in my **.plist** file.

So My **Question** : How can i set this configuration in Visual Studio instead of copying ios platform  folder to the Xcode and build ipa over there?

I tried to keep this configuration in .plist file  in Release Folder of visual studio but that setting was missing on building the app

Answer (score 1):

When you export, make sure to select **Save for iOS App Store Deployment**

[image]

Comment: sorry for the late reply, as you can see in my question that i can able to export using the MAC (i copied the project from platforms in windows vs solution and opened it in the xcode in mac and able to build it over there) without any issue ,but when i am trying to build using the visual studio cordova from windows using the remote agent i can able to get the ipa and upload to itunes connect but with beta entitlement missing.

Comment: can you check if the provisioning profile you used is for App Store Deployment?

Comment: yes, in my build log , i can see that its distribution profile